# cmd command "runas" equivalent in MacOS

Tags: macos, pam

i am facing an issue while using the mac. I need to use that PowerShell command on my mac to run application as domain user

```
runas /netonly /user:user_name "C:\Users\fwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Azure Data Studio\azuredatastudio.exe"
```

I have tried

```
sudo -u user_name /Applications/AzureDataStudio.app
```

it asks password for local user. but in my case user is on External domain

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question a bit what is this means ? "it asks password for local user. but in my case user is on External domain" ??

Comment: I want to open an application with the network user not (local user). as I can do in windows cmd
`runas /netonly /user:user_name` /application name

Answer (score 1):

To run Azure Data Studio (ADS) on your mac and login to SQL Server using Windows authentication instead of a username/password, you use the **kinit** command. I've had best luck using the kinit command through the built-in command window in ADS (you'll be prompted to do so if/when your login fails). Note that your computer needs network access to a kerberos server.

There's some further information about setting this up [HERE](https://port1433.com/2019/04/04/using-ad-authentication-in-azure-data-studio-on-a-non-windows-non-domain-machine/) and [HERE](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/wiki/How-to-enable-Integrated-Authentication-on-macOS-and-Linux-using-Kerberos).

Answer (score 0):

I know this article is old, but did you even try entering "your-userid@domain.whatever" (your own domain user name), in order to try to run the app as that user?
"sudo -u user_name /Applications/AzureDataStudio.app"
So, it might be like this:
sudo -u jsmith@mydomain.com /Applications/AzureDataStudio.app

Basically, I'm having the same issue, and "kinit" looks like one method to solve this. Another method is that, as of a certain version of Mac OS, you can actually "domain join" the Mac workstations now; so that should make accessing and running apps by "domain user / group" much simpler. We have two domains, so we cannot do that; instead, we have to punt and use "kinit".